# Trello Power Up Development - Custom Fields

Tags: trello

**My Research**

I've recently noticed that there is a power up called [Custom Fields](http://blog.trello.com/trello-custom-fields) and after reading the [Trello client library documentation](https://developers.trello.com/power-ups/client-library) I can't see how to produce an input box like the one demonstrated in the custom fields power up.

[image]

What my thought process was is opening a page on a button click in an iframe

```
'card-buttons': function(t, options){
  return [{
    icon: './images/icon.svg',
    text: 'Button Text',
    callback: function(t){
      return t.popup({
        title: "Click To Input Data",
        url: './inputData.html'
      });
    }
  }];
}
```

The above won't work because I don't know how to pass the input values back to the Trello board as I intend to save it in trello's data storage

**Storing the input value**

```
t.set('board', 'private', 'key', value)
```

**Quick Summary**

Adding an input field to a Trello card and storing the input data in data storage so all Trello users can see this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're starting down the right path!

The Custom Fields Power-Up makes use of `t.popup` and `t.set` to manage the data input in the fields. On your `inputData.html` file, you'll want to include the style sheet provided [here](https://developers.trello.com/power-ups/style) so that your input fields look the same as Trello's.

To store the data, you can actually make use of `t.set` from your `inputData.html` if you include the Trello client library *on* the page. Once you've included it on the page, you can set a click listener for your button and then use `t.set` to store the data. A great example of how this is accomplished can be found on this [example Power-Up](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/trello-power-up?path=public/js/settings.js:1:0).